# Why is PyCharm giving error in input() and print() functions - 'Unresolved Reference'?

Tags: python, function, error-handling, pycharm, computer-science

All of my other files (leaving a sopecific) in the project are without error.

Its as shown, only 'Magic-I' is having a problem with `print()` and `input()`
[image]

I shall give you the whole code:

```
outcome = {
    "hi": "Hello",
    "hello": "Hi",
    "what's your name": "Magic-I !",
    "this": "'this' what?",
    "you are mad": "You too.....LEL !!!",
    "your hobby": "Solving problems",
    "fuck off": ".........",
    "i like you": "Me too",
}
help = '''
'calculate' - addition ; subtraction ; multiplication ; division.
'car game' - simple car simulator.
'guess game' - launch a simple guessing game.
'rbi' - launch RBI.
'bye' - exit AI
||type 'help' whenever you need to know these commands||
*It also chat*
'''

print("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print("\nThis is an AI - 'MAGIC I' !")
print("It chats and complete several other tasks !")
print("\nSome key features (type these to access them): ")
print(help)

k = ""

while True:
    res = input("\n> ").lower()
    if res in outcome:
        k = outcome.get(res)+" !"
        print(k)
    elif "name" in res:
        print("Magic-I !")

    elif "fuck" in res:
        print('........')

    elif "parent" in res:
        print("Rakshit")

    elif "master" in res:
        print("Rakshit")

    elif "coder" in res:
        print("Rakshit")

    elif "programmer" in res:
        print("Rakshit")

    elif "calc" in res:
        import calculator
        calculator.calculator()

    elif 'car' in res:
        import CarGame

    elif 'guess' in res:
        import GuessGame

    elif 'rbi' in res:
        import RBI

    elif 'ac' in res:
        print("Turn it on !!!")

    elif 'help' in res:
        print(help)

    elif res == "bye":
        print("Bye..!")
        break

    elif res == "":
        print("You haven't typed anything..!")

    else:
        print("No.!")
```

this is the code......if you want something else i can give you...please help !!!

Folder:
[image]

Hey, when I tried to fix the print() problem it was showing install print() package, something like that...when I clickd it, I got an error:
[image]

Comment: Please: do not repost old questions. It is not how this site works: this site is mostly about getting reference answers to other people.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should remove the pythonpath variable in your ~/.bash_profile
you can do that by using:-
#export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

Comment: Why this would change something?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by changing the text quotations in my input and print, instead of :

```
variable = input("Some Text")
```

Try this :

```
variable = input('Some Text')
```

It worked well with single quotes in my code

Comment: that's a year old question, it was because I messed up with my internal folders (in python)